# (Azure) BrokeredMessage.GetBody<xxx>

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, brokeredmessage

I'm trying to put together a 'generic' subscriber that I can (re)use with `Azure ServiceBus`.

But I'm stuck as follows;
my code once stripped of non essential parts looks like this.

```
Subscribing.Client.OnMessage((recdMessage =>
{
    var msgBody = recdMessage.GetBody<myClass>();
}, options);
```

I want my `msgBody` to be of the type that has been serialised into the body of the message. 
Indeed if `myClass` were to be something like `TelephonyEventMessage` and the message received was of that type then my `msgBody` would be a correctly instantiated/rehydrated object of that type.
But although I can use `recdMessage`. ContentType to get the string name of the class in that message.... I just cant figure what I need to put in `myClass` above.
I'm at the end of my knowledge now and no amount of searches seems to look like an answer for me. Do I need to add a specific version for every type that may exist in my messages?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to receive messages from a subscription if you are expecting a number of different object types:

```
public void ReceiveMessageFromSubscription<T>(string topicPath, string subscriptionName, Action<T> action)
{
    var client = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, topicPath, subscriptionName);

    client.OnMessage((message) =>
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.Information("Processing message");
            action(message.GetBody<T>());
            message.Complete();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, "Error processing message");
            message.Abandon();
        }
    } );
}
```

And then pass in a method which knows how to handle the object, as below. You could have a number of these methods, all calling ReceiveMessageFromSubscription.

```
public void ProcessObject()
{
    _serviceBusService.ReceiveMessageFromSubscription<MyObject>(mytopic, mysubscription, _myobjectService.ProcessObject);
}
```